# Android: Need to get the String from strings.xml with id needs to be selected at run time

Tags: android

In our application we have created strings with id like msg_55164 , msg_55165 .......
Now in our application during run-time we get the ids from the server like 55164 and depending upon that id we need to show the string with id msg_55164. Is it possible to do something like this in Android.

Thanks in Advance!
Help Appreciated.
Bhushan

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this to get and load the `Drawable` dynamically:

```
String drawablePath = "msg_" + id;  //Get here the drawable identifier name     
int drawableID = getResources().getIdentifier(drawablePath,"drawable", getPackageName()); //Get the drawable ID
Drawable draw = getResources().getDrawable(drawableID);
```

Or this for a simple String:

```
String stringPath = "msg_" + id;    
int stringID = getResources().getIdentifier(stringPath,"string", getPackageName());
String str = getResources().getString(stringID);
```

Comment: Well, Alex was faster! Anyway, you can use this way to load any resources available.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Resources.getIdentifier()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) like this

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("msg_500", "string", null);

String s = getString(id);
```